# for loop with auto type over vector of vectors

Tags: c++

In the new versions of c++ it's very convenient to use auto as type and range base for loops to do

```
// instead of
for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
}
// to do
for (auto vi: v) {
}
```

How can I use it for `vector<vector<int>>`?
When I try

```
for (const auto& vi: vvi) {

}
```

compilers complains: declaration of variable 'vi' with deduced type 'const auto'  requires an initializer.

**update:**
turned out everything works perfectly, I just made a silly typo and put '&' after a variable name instead of a type `for (const auto vi&: vvi)`; I used & to avoid creation of new variable every iteration of the loop.

Comment: `compilers complains that v requires an initializer.` [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/n8WZUH)

Comment: Whenever you post a question you should make a [mcve] that contains everything to reproduce the error that you are encountering.  The shown code does not result in that error. If it really does then please include used compiler (and version)  and the settings you use for compiling this.

Comment: yes, my bad. when I tried to create a link with online IDE of the example above - I found the error, a silly typo actually. Also, godbolt.org c++ compiler gave me far more readable error output than a leetcode.com. I wish c++ compilers use simple error output like Rust.

Answer (score 4):

You might use 2 for range:

```
for (const auto& inner: vvi) { // auto is std::vector<int>
    for (auto e: inner) { // auto is int
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```